# where does timestamp of a packet reside

Tags: networking

when a packet goes out libpcap timestamps the packet, but where does the time stamp of packet reside i.e, whether it resides in data of packet.
If on reception side if the same packet is received does the time stamp at transmitted side will be over written at reception side by libpcap.

Comment: libpcap timestamps a packet when it arrives, not when it sends it.

Answer (score 1):

libpcap does not timestamp outgoing packets. On the transmit side, timestamping can be done as a part of some network protocol. For example, with TCP one can use the Timestamp option ([RFC  1323](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1323)). If the TCP timestamp option is enabled, the outgoing packets will most likely be timestamped by the network stack.

On the receive side, libpcap receives the packet from the OS and will rely on the kernel to give it a valid timestamp. The kernel will get the timestamp from either the network interface driver or the networking stack.

The receive timestamp should not be a part of the packet and hence wont overwrite the senders timestamp, which will be a part of the received packet. (as in case of TCP)

Hope that answers your question?